# Change order of 8 divs with bootstrap

Tags: html

I have 8 divs, on desktop and tablet there should be 4 divs side by side, with links that open a div underneath all 4 at full width. on mobile i want the div thats opened by the link to display underneath the div with the corresponding link.

At first I tried a function

```
function resize(){
if($(window).width() < 480)
{
$("#service1").insertAfter("#service-box1");
}
}
```

Now I'm trying to do so with bootstrap, but I don't know which version should be used or how exactly to do it with 8 divs.

Here's the html in desktop order

```
<div id="services-container" class="row">


 <div class="service" id="service-box1">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <a class="learn-more" id="show1" data-href="service1">Learn More</a>
 </div>
 <div class="service" id="service-box2">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <a class="learn-more" id="show2" data-href="service2">Learn More</a>
 </div>
 <div class="service" id="service-box3">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <a class="learn-more" id="show3" data-href="service3">Learn More</a>
 </div>
 <div class="service" id="service-box4">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <a class="learn-more" id="show4" data-href="service4">Learn More</a>
 </div>


 <div class="service-content" id="service-content1">
  <h1>Service1</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="service-content" id="service-content2">
  <h1>Service2</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="service-content" id="service-content3">
  <h1>Service3</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="service-content" id="service-content4">
  <h1>Service4</h1>
 </div>


</div>
```

Here's the html in mobile order

```
<div id="services-container" class="row">

 <div class="service" id="service-box1">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <a class="learn-more" id="show1" data-href="service1">Learn More</a>
 </div>
 <div class="service-content" id="service-content1">
  <h1>Service1</h1>
 </div>

 <div class="service" id="service-box2">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <a class="learn-more" id="show2" data-href="service2">Learn More</a>
 </div>
 <div class="service-content" id="service-content2">
  <h1>Service2</h1>
 </div>

 <div class="service" id="service-box3">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <a class="learn-more" id="show3" data-href="service3">Learn More</a>
 </div>
 <div class="service-content" id="service-content3">
  <h1>Service3</h1>
 </div>

 <div class="service" id="service-box4">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <a class="learn-more" id="show4" data-href="service4">Learn More</a>
 </div>
 <div class="service-content" id="service-content4">
  <h1>Service4</h1>
 </div>

</div>
```

This is how it should display on desktop:
https://imgur.com/IJPUOhi

This is how it should display on mobile (screens 669px and below):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnrim.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox), in conjunction with its [flex-order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items#The_order_property) css attribute.

An example:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.box1,
.box2,
.box3,
.box4 {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.box5 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .box1 {
    order: 1;
  }  
  .box2 {
    order: 3;
  }  
  .box3 {
    order: 4;
  }  
  .box4 {
    order: 5;
  }
  .box5 {
    order: 2;
  }  
  .box1,
  .box2,
  .box3,
  .box4 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1">box 1</div>
  <div class="box2">box 2</div>
  <div class="box3">box 3</div>
  <div class="box4">box 4</div>
  <div class="box5">box 5</div>
</div>
```